# Integrating Drools with JBossESB

Tags: jboss, drools, esb, drools-fusion

In recent weeks I've been researching Drools amongst other CEP/Rule Engines and I believe I would like to use Drools. I also have an JBossESB which is responsible for routing of messages between different services.

Unless I am totally missing the boat, I can't for the life of me see how I would get data into Drools via JBossESB.

Inside of my ESB I have data (facts) that needs to be monitored and routed correctly (some of the data properties also needs to be modified based on other properties in each of the facts, I figured using Drools (a combination of Fusion and Expert) would be the best way to handle this, however, I don't really see in any of the JBoss (or other) documentation how I would get that done.

Is this a cart-before-the-horse situation? Am I totally missing the boat somewhere?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty late to respond...If anyone is still looking please see: http://java.dzone.com/articles/jbossesb-drools-integration